# Reverse string of integers while not reversing the integers themselves

Tags: java, string, recursion, integer, reverse

I'm trying to make a function reverse a string of integers, but am only able to mirror it completely, with the following piece of code I found. (I want to translate it from string to string without arrays or lists, preferably recursively)

```
static String reverseMe(String s) {
if(s.length() == 0)
  return "";
return s.charAt(s.length() - 1) + reverseMe(s.substring(0,s.length()-1));
```

}

So for example (1 2 41) returns (14 2 1) when I really want (41 2 1). I would like some way for Java to start reversing when it encounters a space (or any none-integer) and keep the integers themselves as they are.

Comment: Do you have to use recursion?

Comment: No, I just thought that would make for a nicer solution. We've only just covered it in class.

Comment: Tokenize on space, then reverse the resulting array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modified version of your function using [`String#lastIndexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String reverseMe(String s)
{
  if (s.length() == 0)
     return "";
  int index = s.lastIndexOf(" ");
  if (index == -1) // not found, thus just return the string
     return s;
  else // found, thus concat last part with recursive call
     return s.substring(index + 1) + " " + reverseMe(s.substring(0, index));
}
```

Or you can use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to separate by spaces and just loop through in reverse and concatenate.

```
String reverse(String s)
{
  String reversed = "";
  String[] split = s.split(" ");
  reversed = split[split.length-1];
  for (int i = split.length-2; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    reversed += " " + split[i];
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

Although [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) would make for a more efficient option, since it doesn't require all that string copying.

Comment: That's nifty, but Im not allowed to use lists or arrays. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2307428 See edit - I modified your function appropriately.

Comment: Hey, that second solution was exactly what i was looking for!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it recursively,this would do it!

```
public static String reverseIt(final String inp,final int lastIndex,String out)
{
    int i=lastIndex;
    while(inp.charAt(i)!=' ' && i!=-1){i--;if(i==-1)break;}
    out+=(inp.substring(i+1,lastIndex+1));if(i!=-1)out+=" ";
    if(lastIndex!=0)return reverseIt(inp,i-1,out);
    else return out;
}
```

You can now call it as

```
reverseIt(input,input.length-1,output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use StringTokenized

```
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("1 2 41");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.insert(0, ' ');
        }
        sb.insert(0, st.nextToken());
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

One another solution among these

```
static String reverseMe(String s) {
        if(s.length() == 0)
          return "";
        String sa[] = s.split(" ");
        List<String> newlist = Arrays.asList(sa);
        Collections.reverse(newlist);
        return newlist.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as this.

```
String num="1 2 41";
    StringTokenizer sTok=new StringTokenizer(num, " ");
    String revnum="";
    while(sTok.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        revnum=sTok.nextToken()+" "+revnum;
    }
    System.out.println(revnum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another recursive variant using [Tail call recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

```
public static String reverseMe(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    return reverseMe(s.split(" "), sb);
}

public static String reverseMe(String[] s, StringBuilder sb) {
    if (s.length == 0) {
        return sb.toString().trim();
    } else {
        return reverseMe(Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 1, s.length), sb.insert(0, " ").insert(0, s[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non recursive, guava present.

```
  String input = "123 456 789 tt 012";
  Iterable<String> tokens = Splitter.on(Pattern.compile("[^\\d]")).omitEmptyStrings().split(input);
  for(String token: tokens){
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(token);
       System.out.println(builder.reverse().toString());
  }
```

Or without guava:

```
String input = "123 456 789 tt 012";
    String tokens [] = input.split("[^\\d]+");
    for(String token:tokens){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(token);
        System.out.println(builder.reverse().toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not particular with recursion, the below solution would work.

```
static String reversMe(String str) {

    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

    String strArray = str.split(" ");


    for(int i = strArray.length();i>=0; i--) {

       strBuf.append(strArray[i]).append(" ");  

     }

     return strBuf.toString().trim();     
    }
```